# Is there any way to enable Aqua scrollbars under Mint 20?

Tags: linux-mint, themes, cinnamon

I've been looking through cinnamon-look.org and been finding themes labeled as Aqua that either do not work at all, or do not look anything like the iconic classic Aqua scrollbars, under Mint 20.

I've found one older theme that works with Mint 18.2, but it doesn't work under Mint 20.

Are there any options available?

--UPDATE--

One of the themes I found was an [OSX Mavericks](https://www.cinnamon-look.org/p/1290655/) which installed but, authentically, had no Aqua scrollbars. I also found an [OSX Cheetah](https://www.cinnamon-look.org/p/1290811/) released by the same person(s), but I downloaded it and couldn't get it to register as visible to Cinnamon's Themes applet.

Comment: One breadcrumb comment: I released [a VMware virtual machine with Linux Mint 18.2 and such Aqua as I could get working](https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/sourcecode/Aqua%202.0.zip), in [Changes in Mac OSX Over Time: The Good Parts](https://cjshayward.com/mac-good-parts/).

Answer (score 0):

[I found a real treasure trove for nostalgic Apple themes for Linux.](https://www.cinnamon-look.org/c/1300313/)

I apparently was not triggering a reread of `~/.themes`. The brute force of a reboot magically made themes appear.

The remainder of the installation, after finding the treasure trove, was relatively "follow your nose."

I had no interesting difficulties after downloading the theme I wanted and rebooting.